# chrome.storage undefined in React chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am working on a chrome extension that renders a react app and appends it to the current webpage.

I have added the permissions to my manifest file:

```
// manifest.json    
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
```

The app is appended to the webpage using the contents.ts file:

```
// contents.ts
if (!document.getElementById("mysecretid")) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "mysecretid";
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("controlPanel.js");

    document.body.parentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-chrome-storage?activeTab=readme npm package for storing data locally and my control panel component has a simple UI that uses the npm package as shown in their basic example like so:

```
import { useChromeStorageLocal } from "use-chrome-storage";

const ControlPanel = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [render, setRender] = useState(true);
    const locale = "en";

    const [value] = useChromeStorageLocal("counterLocal", 0);

    console.log("value is", value);

    return (
        <div>Some components...</div>
    );
};
```

But this results in the render tree crashing with the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onChanged')
```

Of the corresponding minified line:

```
return chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(t),
```

Why is chrome.storage undefined in this case and how do to fix it?

Comment: Since you run it in a `script` element in the web page, your code runs in the normal JS context of the page which doesn't have access to `chrome.storage` API. There are two solutions: 1) use CustomEvent messaging between content.ts and controlPanel.js so that content.ts will access chrome.storage and send the result back to controlPanel.js via CustomEvent. 2) Put your entire app inside an iframe.html that is exposed in `web_accessible_resources` e.g. using react-frame-component.